# How to use a local database client against a cloud database if the only access is through a bastion pod

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, mysql-workbench, bastion-host

I have a MySql RDS database that is not publicly exposed. I also have a pod that can act as a bastion with `kubectl exec`. How would I be able to connect my local MySql Workbench to this RDS database?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to your DB from local machine using kubectl port-forward command.
If you don't already have a pod running in the cluster, you can create it with the command:

```
kubectl run ${NAME} --image=alpine/socat  -it --tty --rm --expose=true --port=${DB_PORT} tcp-listen:${DB_PORT},fork,reuseaddr tcp-connect:${DB_ENDPOINT}:${DB_PORT}
```

Once the pod is up and running, use command:

```
kubectl port-forward service/<NAME> ${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}
```

In your MySql Workbench, replace DB_URL with localhost and connection should be forwarded from your machine to the database, with the pod acting as bastion.